# Reading Twitter RSS with Google Feeds API

Tags: javascript, twitter, google-feed-api

I have written this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                        google.load("feeds", "1");
            function initialize() {

            var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=HMTL5");
            feed.setNumEntries(100);
            feed.includeHistoricalEntries();
            //feed.setResultFormat(google.feeds.Feed.XML_FORMAT);
            feed.load(function(result) {
            if (!result.error) {
            for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
            var entry = result.feed.entries[i];

            alert(entry.title);
            alert(entry.author);
            alert(entry.WHAT_SHOULD_I_TYPE_HERE);

}
```

I am able to get the title and author, but not the image. I need to extract the user image URL from  tag but don't know how. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get an Answer to your Question? Why not add the following line under 'var entry =' and post the result:

```
var entry = result.feed.entries[i];

console.log(entry);
```

Or post the URL TAG output